# Loss sequence for glmnet

Tags: r, lasso, glmnet

Is the loss sequence returned by cv.glmnet (the slot "cvm") on the standardized variable scale or the original scale?  This only affects the penalty part of the loss, I think.  In other words, are models obtained by calling cv.glmnet with standardize=TRUE comparable to those obtained with standardize=FALSE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you look at the help for `cv.glmnet`, you will notice it has as its final "parameter": `...`

The parameter explanation below tells you that you can pass in any parameter there that `glmnet` supports (e.g.: `standardize=FALSE`), and all `glmnet` fits used during the crossvalidation will receive these parameters.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question.  It's possible that e.g standardize=TRUE will give you the loss sequence back on the original scale, right?

Comment: The scaling only affects the way the model is fit (mainly because the relative importance of the variables changes). The results that are returned (i.e. the estimated parameters) are always returned in their original scale, regardless of this  parameter. Whether you calculate predicted values with scaled parameters and scaled data or with both unscaled will give the same results, so it should not matter for any predictive measure, as long as all fits happen the same way (scaled or not).